# Responsive CSS, with viewport meta tag but still looks bad

Tags: html, css

Hey so I have this little issue with my main page, it looks okey in mobile, except the text is not centered and it "cuts off" at the right side, mainly because the text goes over the orange box and the text color is the same as the background.

I do have viewport on my code already, that is what makes the site look little better on mobile.. but I think I need some help fixing this issue mentioned above.

This is the portion of the code that has text overflow..

```
        <div class="section">
            <article>
                <h1>Discord bot development community</h1>
                <p>ByteBots' BotLab is mainly focuses on bot development and sharing knowledge between users in the community. Join now our Discord server and community forums, no matter how new or old you are to programming, you are still welcome!</p>
                <a href="https://forums.bytebots.xyz" class="mainbtn"><i class="fas fa-comments"></i> forum</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="https://bytebots.xyz/invite" target="_blank" class="mainbtn"><i class="fab fa-discord"></i> discord</a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="https://twitter.com/ByteBots" target="_blank" class="mainbtn"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i> our twitter</a>
            </article>
        </div>
```

Now the CSS for those tags are here

```
body {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Staatliches;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color:  #23272a;
    background-color: #23272a;
}

.section {
    background-color: #ff6a00;
    color:  #23272a;
    display: block;
}

article {
    display: table;
    max-width: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 100px 50px;
}
```

Now what does the site look now? Well it looks like this on mobile
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLQO5.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, I fixed my issue by adding one thing to my `theme.css`, hope this can help some other people too..

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```